# GetHttpRequestData() and SOAP Web Service Request in ColdFusion 8

Tags: soap, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Currently, we are using `GetHttpRequestData().headers` to get real IP address of User. However, we are facing following issue. when we try to call SOAP web service request, we receive following  error `Premature end of file`. I already searched the web and found out that there is bug in **`ColdFusion 8.0`**.

I don't know if this bug is resolved yet.

Is there any alternate solution?

Please help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the SOAP request coming in to ColdFusion from a client and that is where you are getting the error or is a user hitting a coldfusion page that is then making a soap request to some other service and that is generating the error?

Comment: I developed Coldfusion Web Service (nothing but Coldfusion Component) that client can use to access data. Client is making web service request using SOAP. I have my entire web service components in a \webservice direction where I have application.cfm file. In application.cfm file, I have One include file (block.cfm). The purpose of this to make sure someone is not hacking the site. Within this file, I have code to extract client's REAL IP address using GetHttpRequestData().headers. This is where, I have error. Follow, this link for more information…http://www.petefreitag.com/item/733.cfm

Comment: If you comment out the line that gets the IP address, does it then work fine? Would cgi.remote_addr give you the same information?

Comment: No, We do need to get Real IP address of a client. Reason, we are using load balancer.

Comment: Gotcha. Found another post about it here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1602-GetHTTPRequestData-Breaks-The-SOAP-Request-Response-Cycle-In-ColdFusion.htm . Amazing that they haven't addressed this anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have check adobe and some other web site. No luck.

Comment: any other suggestion about getting real IP address of client without using GetHttpRequestData().headers

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same issue.  I don't know if you've found a solution yet but the workaround I found is using getPageContext().getRequest().getHeader("name of header here") to retrieve the request header I'm looking for. This doesn't break to SOAP calls like getHttpRequestData.